# Standard Deviation for row in table python

Tags: python, arrays

Basically what i am trying to do is calculate the standard deviation of each row in the table array. I have tried everything imaginable but cant get it to execute right.

the array looks like this

```
array = [
[  4,  6,  1, -3,-12],
[  9, 14, -4, 32,  0],
[ 22, -3, 12, -2,  8],
[  4,  4,  4,  4,  4]]
```

python code:

```
from file import array 
for row in array:
mean=sum(row)/len(row)
print("Std Dev=",(sum( (x-mean)**2.0 for x in row ) / float(len(row)) )**0.5)
```

Results:

```
Std Dev= 6.368673331236263
Std Dev= 12.6237870704476
Std Dev= 9.28654941299512
Std Dev= 0.0
```

Comment: Make your life easy and use the superb [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html) package. Then put your data in a dataframe.

Comment: i cant use any packages

Answer (score 2):

There is already a package that does this.  To get the standard deviation of each row of `array`:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: array = [
[  4,  6,  1, -3,-12],
[  10, 14, -4, 32,  0],
[ 22, -3, 10, -2,  8],
[  3,  4,  4,  4,  2]]

In [18]: np.array(array).std(1)
Out[18]: array([  6.37,  12.61,   9.12,   0.8 ])
```

Incidentally, if we had used `np.array(array).std(0)`, we would have gotten the standard deviation of each column.

#### Without `numpy`

With Python3 and no imported modules:

```
array = [
        [  4,  6,  1, -3,-12],
        [  10, 14, -4, 32,  0],
        [ 22, -3, 10, -2,  8],
        [  3,  4,  4,  4,  2]]
for row in array:
    mean=sum(row)/len(row)
    print("Std Dev=",(sum( (x-mean)**2.0 for x in row ) / float(len(row)) )**0.5)
```

This produces the output:

```
Std Dev= 6.368673331236263
Std Dev= 12.611106216347558
Std Dev= 9.121403400793104
Std Dev= 0.8
```

#### Alternate Formula

Depending on the circumstances, the formula for standard deviation may have either `n` or `n-1` in the denominator where `n` is the number of data points.  The calculations above used `n`.  The solution using `n-1` is below:

```
array = [
        [  4,  6,  1, -3,-12],
        [  9, 14, -4, 32,  0],
        [ 22, -3, 12, -2,  8],
        [  4,  4,  4,  4,  4]]
for row in array:
    mean=sum(row)/len(row)
    print("Std Dev=",(sum( (x-mean)**2.0 for x in row ) / float(len(row)-1) )**0.5)
```

This produces the results:

```
Std Dev= 7.120393247567159
Std Dev= 14.11382301150188
Std Dev= 10.382677881933928
Std Dev= 0.0
```

Comment: i cant use numpy because our teacher isnt allowing that for now

Comment: @user3571363 Teachers can be like that.  A solution without numpy has been added.

Comment: glad you understand haha but i tried that code for a different array and it didnt print the right standard deviation

Comment: @user3571363 Which version of python are you using?  Also, would you update your question with the new array and the (incorrect) results that you got?

Comment: i am using python3.4 and updated my question. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3571363 I see the new array.  What makes you think that the results are incorrect?

Comment: its suppose to be 7.120, 14.114, 10.383, 0.000

Comment: @user3571363 That makes it clear. See updated answer.  In the original code you posted, you used the formula `under_root = total_sum *1.0/length` which is good under some circumstances.  The results that you quote as being correct, however, use a different formula than that.  The answer now shows code for both formulas.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is really that you're not doing what you intend.  Look at your `mean()` method; you are iterating over the array. What is each element of that array?  *An array in itself*. However, you are returning the mean of the very first inner array as the result of the function, thus you're getting a "mean" for one row of the table, based not on the row's length but the number of rows in the table.

Even though Python is dynamically typed, try to think about your code in terms of a series of transformations.  For example, the `mean()` method would be (presumably) a method which takes a list of lists and returns a single integer as the value for the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is actually a list of lists, so you need to double-iterate over it. For a simple 2D case, this will work:

```
import math
def total_2D(data):
    return sum(sum(row) for row in data)

def length_2D(data):
    return sum(len(row) for row in data)

def stDev_2D(data):
    length = length_2D(data)
    mean = total_2D(data) / length
    diff_sqr = sum(sum((i - mean) ** 2 for i in row) for row in data)
    return math.sqrt(diff_sqr / length)

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
standard = stDev(data)
print(standard)
```

You can do this more generally, for any number of dimensions:

```
import math
def list_total(data):
    if hasattr(data[0], '__iter__'):
        return sum(list_total(item) for item in data)
    else:
        return sum(data)

def list_len(data):
    if hasattr(data[0], '__iter__'):
        return sum(list_len(item) for item in data)
    else:
        return len(data)

def list_diffSqr(data, mean):
    if hasattr(data[0], '__iter__'):
        return sum(list_diffSqr(item, mean) for item in data)
    else:
        return sum((item - mean) ** 2 for item in data)

def list_stDev(data):
    n = list_len(data)
    mean = list_total(data) / n
    return math.sqrt(list_diffSqr(data, mean) / n)

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
standard = stDev(data)
print(standard)
```

Note that this will only work if the depth is consistent. E.g. `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` works but `[[1,2],3,[4,5]]` doesn't.

Comment: The solution, first code you posted i tried it just gave me a an initial syntax error. Why is that?

Comment: @user3571363 It looks like I made a typo. Line 12 should read `(i - mean) ** 2`, not `(i - m) ** 2`. It's fixed in the answer now.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the issue with the error.  I changed m to mean in my code but it still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easy and use the superb [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html) package:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [[  4,  6,  1, -3,-12],
                    [  10, 14, -4, 32,  0],
                    [ 22, -3, 10, -2,  8],
                    [  3,  4,  4,  4,  2]], columns=['foo','bar','baz','qux','cor'])    
df['cor'].std()

>>> 8.3864970836060824
```

Comment: He cannot use any thirdparty module, only Python stdlib

Comment: Oh ok, he added that after the original question